# How to get the parent node of a given child node using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, xml

I am new to PowerShell. I have to write a script which can return me the first parent(node) value by passing the child node.

I have the following XML. When I pass my PowerShell script the value "AAA", it should return "parent2", and when I pass "III", it should return "parent311".

Can someone help me write this script?

XML:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <parent2>
      <child>AAA</child>
    </parent2>
    <parent3>
      <child>BBB</child>
      <child>CCC</child>
      <child>DDD</child>
    </parent3>
    <parent4>
      <child>EEE</child>
    </parent4>
    <parent5>
      <child>FFF</child>
    </parent5>
  </parent>
  <parent21>
    <parent211>
      <child>GGG</child>
    </parent211>
    <parent311>
      <child>HHH</child>
      <child>III</child>
      <child>JJJ</child>
    </parent311>
    <parent411>
      <child>KKK</child>
    </parent411>
    <parent511>
      <child>LLL</child>
    </parent511>
  </parent21>
</root>
```

Comment: I am able to to display child tag details, I don't know how to get the parent tag details by giving the child value. And i am new to this powershell. If there is a option to reslove this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to the child node, you can get its parent node using the appropriately named [`ParentNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode.aspx) property. For instance, with the XML file you posted:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content file.xml)
$child = $xml.SelectSingleNode("root/parent/parent2/child")
$child.ParentNode.Name
```

Of course, you probably use some other method to get the child node than `SelectSingleNode()`, but it serves to illustrate the example. The output of the above would be:

```
parent2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But i have to write a script as where we have to pass only "child" not a full path as "root/parent/parent2/child" If we have any options to get in that way please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @kumar Well, you said that you are "able to to display child tag details", from which I understand that you already have code to take the name of the child node and get a reference to it. `SelectSingleNode()` in my answer was just an example, you should replace it with the actual code that you have. Or, if I misunderstood, then perhaps you could edit the question to show what code you do have and what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to filter:

```
## Change child node here:
$childnode = "AAA"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content file.xml
## XPath:
$childxpath = "/root/*/*[./child='$childnode']"
## Get node:
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode($childxpath, $null)
## Show selected node name:
Write-Host $node.name
```

In the XPath `/root/*/*[./child='$childnode']`:

- The first `*` matches: `<parent>`&`<parent21>`
- The second `*` matches: `<parent2>`,`<parent3>`... & `<parent211>`,`<parent311>`...
- `[./child='$childnode']` matches: child nodes named `child`, and the value equals to `$childnode`